# How to download file using url which getting authenticated via sso

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have URL= "https://Path-to-url&Action=Download&format=CSV" which i am hitting into browser it is able to download csv file with correct data because it is getting authenticated with SSO. But when i am using python it is downloading file but getting authentication error. I gave mt creds as well for authentication but it didn't worked. Here is my code.

```
url = "https://Path-to-url&Action=Download&format=CSV"
user,password = 'user-name', 'password'
response = requests.get(url,auth=(user, password))
open("BGCustomersbySKU-OCI.csv", "wb").write(response.content)
```

Error which i am getting

````
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
if(hash.indexOf("#") == -1){
hash="#"+hash
}
document.myForm.action = document.myForm.action+hash;
}
document.myForm.submit();
}
</script><head><base target="_self"></head><body onLoad="submitForm()"><noscript><p>JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.</p></noscript><form action="https://login.com/mysso/signon.jsp" method="post" name="myForm"><!------------ DO NOT REMOVE -------------><!----- loginform renderBrowserView -----><!-- Required for SmartView Integration --><input type="hidden" name="bmctx" value="A38E9D6A49EE1821DBE253981B42CC214C0510AD855BCE41264037D8AC1D3C3C"><input type="hidden" name="contextType" value="external"><input type="hidden" name="username" value="string"><input type="hidden" name="contextValue" value="%2Foam"><input type="hidden" name="challenge_url" value="https%3A%2F%2Flogin..com%2Fmysso%2Fsignon.jsp"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="sercure_string"><input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="5378585642023862909"><input type="hidden" name="authn_try_count" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="OAM_REQ" value="VERSION_4~xTenNhZzYIV523%2b3AJNb%2fG2zmo5aYdsS49LwauGiNsBQAI39zBBwx3cEBrX%2f%2ftlBIZEZK7vI1L%2f%2fHbdrGxAXw8MLpEF3NCnVEB0vFA7RkNhXJ%2ffNqmpOVz6Rem9QskdR%2fIdEDQ%2bIi5iZPYoUb04lGIlKps2VJs6pVw4nS%2bDofQx%2bLUIg4sgYmNIXkNdnSa7e3U9pPmhpEjDjeofFQg25SELJsiQfHfqEEmIGlWkRP4xWch0xQ8mmQiTRHrvPH1wvUFBUhe9KGVKFMzDdaQX3bN3ThqpyBg7OarNBrlFjH61VF%2biWcqXDrzgezgMUBTBJf4JUdcQZa%2bvHM1k88EpcR5mr0SLtZIoKl%2b700LqFuRcVVUXeyGEpYoQF7oj8vtgtx2lrXLb7t%2b8VfkGTCD4YEkIOVA7jlIzjqVYdlwv7Ex2cE%2bC17Fqytt0ST5JB3RT%2fmn7Mz1aAEvVmkM7Z74I6GzcgaGQRfDjA2Uko85yeuWAcF0ZyJyI%2fio4ty%2fYKha8N7DHuvthBxTZ8WtYS42sKfEDeo%2fdPgt99xd9gyfw5QRY5XDObPV4hs%2fmeHYA%2bnloXqXjcvpIb2bi0ek2V73yreVCiuBDbAZiD8kIuoklp8siZI4VX43gWyufwCC51EqCZWowlr1RVtE3GxusbJj34Vju5RG%2fLIpG%2b%2fM%2bEy6GdmPc%2brukVtFrQCq%2fiGgA4mu%2fZzhjK2bMs%2fFL551h3inyfalrhN9a0BDz2WyCrSFOqbKLuBBjfEHMi2ygj81fJgbNRjh3dhX1K5Wy7zo%2bx6BwU29mTTkmAo7%2bYY0Ws5q722YPiQSSMIGV3wKMz%2fVDNqW9IMNXw7B989gTyzc4gu%2fmpI9cDbPAwP%2bjs8tJIAug0PvIMlgphKgEsHLiZbrVoZXm1FrO9HQM8sDMZufdajSoyMDu2bzAPBePl0Z4RSc3RkolOtxweZbpkwTAatBJzin%2bHebYdeWCGt1yDCgUphw27teCWGo6Oszjcl4g3vjyfpy8C%2fFbVzP1GNs2HhcYthCTS%2fPWEOI7ox7GyPe95KFMMB7Bk1VD9LWeh%2fUufLRqXSV4tlx809C1Sg2E5O0yU67TPHyQLEGygOz0FyPIeHyw1L3OAu9lsPrtwX2qUfz5Ei8QUMvlQefEd%2f0c6z9zV4atbgAZ47i4kKl0YVAQd8D5i6rQALWuDEjP3s7%2bBX1jbExu5JGCU%2fqQ2cZmaUTz2Rs16S6OQD1zyrJbPhnY4Ni44FPUjgYUAbhD3K8c9j5CF4ve04w8HtfhKLhDgwvzH4mAi1xHZaWfyYuPqtrRfiBYQ01akX%2bq5QOJTLVCwDpOFEZ%2bVgndtS0PoHi%2bZ6%2fzCIhoiboXokykNj12hzRlae44EO%2f6YkjspgCBiU7iMZtZN0maNrrh7GxKrcc9VyTrQ0OayIXkFqTx0NnZc%2fRVp5llwtnjJDCze%2fU%2bXjh2p6j%2fob0AJL2k2%2brCkVr3IZVrYZHCP3ExAyIkTx%2f4mDUUaP%2fLSqHCJtmN2iOzwCj%2fGCRGeQ1xOKC3ZsYz21CpRfgjTciQGO8Lb3apH2pz7GfuUvkpWdz79zAsVLmF3ey%2bpR2QDoDZTgeZnVm7BGLutgdwM6sGT9V057P4pBeREqKfPQ6eWgKDKuo4Jfe0EFzLlvsckHf%2bpV3HYGORGWKSmuGZwlWkrXoX3XF0M06xpOTBiHme%2bfBOyLgMNRf0mlQeEln0rBR8xwLI9siT15keYVEC8N2DylWfaQPGlprUDo%2bVbpUrr1apaa1arFIf7rerNzNKnPQ3W1DAphvg1cFVS8DIveJP0iWFnxd%2bptZHkOfdDt6mT5ILlPrL1C9LW%2f0nsBXwztrWm9fWJAQlUJcqTdJpZzxWBmoZB%2fYkVJGkGWV9NRlU2XnNd8%2ff5mOMHQdJt%2bnz6yHEExiF0HdI4AnHiO6M27ijjhsoaYx0SAfmcUmCEkaxkkghSB9HdZ3VyWDK16vcfb8sXEmORI1kDOkC%2baioVMNA19uFkPinYcqZ1DJjR9UpxOwg3j4fs35S3NRY%2bnwa08a23rDI2TCGqMT%2bnZJ5fhEfeG0OgItSTddWrZaVqguDlMR0BHTNZTvnVFVbBQ%2bMEuQGLlDgpdtoS%2f9fZCj6W9O%2fAZQqMXmVMKC5UI0HkhwXokDzy%2f6ZexwICQ4jr3P44%2b9uJZ%2bAgyP%2b4ZiaNp9QCRhfxFvKX4lM%2fRRTQOPbwscOenPnrTNz%2fFxOR1I3g4iD7sRz2F9fNeEbdq0SynbsyDKWs%2bME%2buV%2fnqjQHsH1HNoaOd10aqBmxa3oYFHX7x1EHVOTqY7SvE%2fUfBF7V5f%2f3vj2hysnLPfMBzE7h8dxWLhtln2GG7TAMsD6cmwDQ4WdjKWIjL%2buHxC%2bs81NbNAkEpE81HPJm%2bVF19BQc%2bS76%2fKpoTNvJcmHpqu4w8Z3OBdsS6ag%2fK6JEQniaVCr6BY0qL6NRtgBzVu6NLThUlVTxSMtkb35a9qQkgFeOfV1UhxS0rN5ybeZNzfFi4wIbctda0%2bI0lB4CLniJoprc32cY5y2C5lxUW1EHCVMeTA565nbg%2bq%2f91wA1NVvz1lNlsbzPfiGOGwovkmZTR5p%2fTe0OGH9tTBFpStgOPDJCU2o0v1WkisHPBU54COdG0fJUZp%2bm1IDQ2K%2fkGXJZLv4tJLeTgUeRJLxMw53K2M0rGZATmYEQ4HXaPPjMaahMOieph1DHDL9B26uZZHKNCS5ZpuFRX9E33rtDVFOvHXDNg%2bxjEl%2b410ujwwCRnu1ej3wasPI1geUlsDA2rfxKrsTM%2b8oMDMbWT6oTBy2WMV%2ff3dF6cmFUQmSQwF8rPAK7nmyA7%2f%2bdCxYz7ddgNirC%2```
````